# How to add a datepicker by id dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using jQuery 1.4.4 and I'm stuck trying to add a datepicker dynamically by id.  Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#ListTableBody').find('input[id^="PickDate."]').each(function () {
        alert(this.id);
        $(this.id).datepicker();
    });
});
```

I'm using a table that dynamically generates the id's on the fly.  The code above finds each of the id's and I verified it using the alert.  As I loop through, this.id shows I've got the right id and input, but the datepicker doesn't work for some reason?  Also, I don't throw any errors.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('#ListTableBody').find('input[id^="PickDate."]').each(function() {                 
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

no need to get the `id` attribute - you can make `this` a jQuery object immediately

Comment: Yes that worked.  I don't feel smart now, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to do something like this if you want to use the ID for it:

```
$("#"+this.id).datepicker();
```

But it's much easier to just do:

```
$(this).datepicker();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a class instead. IDs are only supposed to be used once per document, and the fact you're applying `each()` to your ID selector suggests you may have more than one instance on your page.

Instead, opt for a descriptive class name such as `.datepicker`. Advantage is you can then have more than one on your page, and can also initialise datepickers on them with an expression like such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

No need for the `each()` loop if you're not doing anything else. If you want to restrict datepickers to inputs within a certain area, such as `#ListTableBody` (which I'd again advise the use of a class name so you can have more than one on your page if you wish) then just change the selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ListTableBody').find('input.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: the selector the OP used was a starts with selector - so no problem with using this ....

Comment: The ids are unique so there is no problem there.  I agree with you that the class is the preferred jQuery principle.  So for now I'll use the id's and then refactor when I have time using a class.  Very good answer!

Comment: I'm using Struts2, so I had to find out about the cssClass attribute to get the class associated with the tag, but it's a much cleaner solution.  Excellent example!

Answer (score 0):

could put the same class for each control you need to use as a datepicker.

```
    <script>
       $(function() {   
            $('.class').datepicker();
      });

    </script>
```

Comment: Why is that?, is only necessary